# How to setup a home network for maximum flexibility

Tags: router, home-networking, adsl-router

I am buying some new boxes for my home network, and would like to know what kind of boxes I should have great flexibility the next few years for monitoring and control?

What kind of (Open source) software should I be able to run?

Boxes..Just a powerful router or a router + mini PC?

Recommendations for properties of the router?  Mini PC?

I prefer open source, but how is the stuff from Amazon/Google?

Examples of control:

1. Have a good overview of everything going on in the network.
2. VPN, including directing to external VPN based on use/device.
3. Combine Internet gateways.
4. Optimize and prioritize traffic.

At this point it is just looking to have the right boxes for moving in the right direction in the future.  I am not looking for final solutions, or opening boxes.  Also it is to be always on, without sound and heat, relatively cheap.

Comment: Product and software recommendations are off topic at Superuser.

Comment: I am not asking for specific products and recommendations?

Comment: Then I have no idea specifically what you are asking. Everything you are looking at can be handled by a soft router like PFSense, ClearOS, Devil Linux, etc. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_and_firewall_distributions) or any mid to high end SOHO router cable of running DD-WRT/OpenWRT.

Comment: @acejavelin : so everything should be in the router?  Last time I checked router did not have that much hardware, and also not mainstream that can run open source.

Comment: My 3+ year old Asus RT-N66U can run DD-WRT and do everything your requesting and still maintain 750Mbps throughput... And you can purchase one factory refurbished for around $75USD easily. So yes, that is exactly what I'm saying

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so broad and advanced it is sufficient for a doctor degree study.

Linux router project can handle everything you ask and all you need is an old PC and as many nics as you need subnet separation and gateways to internet. A lot of PCI(e) cards with upto 5 nics in one slot is available. Just prepare for RTFM and a lot of study. There is nothing prepared and ready for delivery for what you want to do. You actually need to teach yourself networking and *nix. Well, unless you want to pay somebody to set it up, but as I understand you, this is partly also to learn.

Comment: Think I will limit myself to commercial boxes:-)  A second internet connection would be through a wireless connection anyway, no extra cards.